# Access IIS Express Web Service from winforms project

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, web-services, iis

everyone. I've tried to find a question or article based on what I need to do, but without success.

I have a web project, which I run in IIS Express (this website needs a certificate, so I can't put it in my local IIS). In this project, there's a webservice which needs to be used in a winforms project (it's basically a server-client structure). The problem is that, even enabling the web project to use SSL, and being able to access the service via URL in the browser, the Client-side project does not find this webservice. Although I was able to update the service reference, when I run the integration test, for example, the test fails with the following message:

> *TestOptifuelInfomax.TipsAndPushServerTest.GetAllDraftTips threw exception:  System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was
>   no endpoint listening at 
>   `https://localhost:44300/Services/myservice.svc` that could accept the
>   message. This is  often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error  (404)
>   Not Found.*

Does anyone have an idea of what to do? Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: I had inserted in the code a "true" validation for CertificateValidationCallback, since I knew that IIS Express SSL access is not "trustworthy". Just in a matter of testing, I removed it and tested the code again. Then, the error was the following:

> system.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: could not establish trust 
>   relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> 
>   System.Security,Authentication.AuthenticationException: the remote certificate is 
>   invalid according to the validation procedure.

So, it seems that the service configuration works, and the 404 error only happens when I change the callback check. The code is the following:

```
ServicePointManager.ServiceCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, policyErrors) => true;
```

Comment: Did you add the Web Service reference by right-clicking the Winforms project and selecting Add Web Reference?

Comment: Yes, the reference is in the project and in config file as well. If the webservice wasn't referenced in the project, the error would be about the non-existing endpoint.

Comment: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException

Comment: the error is different when the endpoint in config file is wrong or inexistent. The main error here is 404.

Comment: Try getting it working without the https/SSL first.

Comment: "System.ArgumentException: The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid: expected 'https'."